# Why does it not show the value when it is 0?

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregate

I have to use aggregate for my assignment but I'm facing this problem

when I try to get the count of credit that are more than 2, it works because the count value is more than 0, but when i try finding the count of credit that is more than 6, where value of the count is 0, it does not print

db.Subject.aggregate([{"$match":{"subject.credit":{"$gt":2}}},{"$count": "Total"}])

> {"Total" : 7}

db.Subject.aggregate([{"$match":{"subject.credit":{"$gt":6}}},{"$count": "Total"}])

> does not print cause value is 0

I expected the out put to show {"Total" : 0} but it does not show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `$match` stage returns no document, as a result of which the subsequent stage (`$count`) doesn't come into the picture at all

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. I'm still pretty weak at mongo query, is there a way to show value that is 0?

Comment: ok nvm I got it. Thanks